# Vue.js passing events up to parents in components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue app like this:

```
<div id="example">

  <event-emitting-component @clicked="methodOnRootInstance"></event-emitting-component>

  <event-emitting-component-parent></event-emitting-component-parent>

  <div v-for="click in clicks">
    {{ click }}
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the JS for it:

```
// Child
Vue.component('event-emitting-component', {
  template: '<div class="event-emitting-component" @click="$emit(\'clicked\')">Event emitter</div>'
});
// Parent
Vue.component('event-emitting-component-parent', {
  template: '<div class="event-emitting-component-parent">' +
  'A custom parent!'+
  '<event-emitting-component></event-emitting-component>' + // <-- Please note child component
  '</div>'
});
// create a root instance
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    clicks : []
  },
  methods : {
    methodOnRootInstance : function(){
      this.clicks.push('Element clicked');
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to play with it it is also here:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/QgbwPG?editors=1010

When you click the top child component a click is registered on the root element. Perfect.

When the child component is nested inside a parent (the second component in the example), obviously I can't add a `@clicked="methodOnRootInstance"` as that method doesn't exist inside the component.

**What is the best way to pass an event up through a number of nested components?**

I've made a stripped back example here, but in reality some components are two or three levels deep. Is the answer (what I think it is) that inside the parent component I would have the following:

```
Vue.component('event-emitting-component-parent', {
  template: '<div class="event-emitting-component-parent">' +
  'A custom parent!'+
  '<event-emitting-component @clicked="passClicked"></event-emitting-component>' + // <-- Please note child component
  '</div>',
  'methods': {
    passClicked : function(){
      this.$emit('clicked')
    }
  }
});
```

And then in the html template add the same:

```
<event-emitting-component-parent @clicked="methodOnRootInstance"></event-emitting-component-parent>
```

I know I can get it to work like this, however it doesn't seem very elegant. I've looked in the docs and there are functions such as `sync` although I don't think it's what I need, I'm struggling to find the correct approach.

Bonus question: can vuex help with stuff like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type of problem `vuex` is designed to solve, however, before you consider adding an extra layer of complexity to your app, you may be able to get away with a simple global event bus, which is simply an empty `Vue` object to emit events onto, which can then be listened for by any component in your app, bypassing the `parent-child` chain:

```
const bus = new Vue({});

Vue.component('comp-1', {
  template: `<div>Comp 1 <button @click="emitClick">Click</button></div>`,
  methods: {
     emitClick(){
       bus.$emit('comp-1-click');
     }
  }
})


Vue.component('comp-2', {
  template: `<div><comp-1></comp-1></div>`,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created(){
    bus.$on('comp-1-click',() => {
      console.log('Comp 1 clicked');
    });
  }
})
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oatLhzLp/

Comment: That's a really good call, thanks. I might give vuex a go as my actual app is about a bazillion times as complicated. I have copied your example in a fork and have everything working, and it works exactly as I want. Thanks.